# python 2.7 unicode greek characters using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, unicode, label

I have this coode to plot a figure:

```
plt.plot(x,y, color = "blue", label = u'\u03C9')
```

￼
The unicode don't work in plot label, but it works when I try

```
print(u'\u03C9')
```

Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Run `plt.legend()` to show the labels.

You can see a working version here: https://gist.github.com/davidbrai/742de3cb7def6da8f125e4572e691ee4

Comment: fig2 = plt.figure()
    plt.axvline(fy, color = "red")
    x_tensao_n = Verif[:,15]
    y_tensao_n = Verif[:,0]
    plt.plot(x_tensao_n,y_tensao_n, color = "blue", label = u'\u03C9')
    plt.title("Von Mises")
    plt.legend(loc="upper right", frameon=False)
    plt.ylabel("[m]")
    plt.xlabel("[MPa]")
    plt.savefig('Von Mises - ULS.jpeg',dpi=100)
    plt.show()
    plt.close(fig2)

Comment: the legend show a rectangular insted the greek character